# Search function in listView

Tags: android, listview, search

I want to search for a product name in listView, but nothing displays inside the list after I key in some text inside search text field. I'm not using ArrayAdapter, but I'm using the ResourceCursorAdapter.

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                helper = new ComicsData(this);
                helper.open();
                listSearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                listSearch.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
                model = helper.getAllProduct(list);
                startManagingCursor(model);
                adapter=new ShoppingListAdapter(this, model);

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher=new TextWatcher(){

         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                //String search=listSearch.getText().toString();
                //int textLength=search.length();
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }

        };
```

ShoppingListAdapter

```
class ShoppingListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

        private final String CN = null;

        public ShoppingListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, R.layout.productrow, c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    @Override
        public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            listName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.produtName);
    listName.setText(helper.getProductName(c));
```

Anybody know my mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need provide your adapter with an instance of [FilterQueryProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html). This provider takes your filter query and returns cursor with all found items.

Comment: is it i need use LIKE statement in my query part?

Answer (score 1):

After changing text in listSearch get items according to search text `helper.getProducts(searchText);` and  call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`